# Errno 10013 An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden - python 2.7

Tags: python, email, programación-funcional

Estoy intentando crear un script que envie un correo electronico simple a traves de gmail con `python 2.7` pero a la hora de ejecutar el codigo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Connection to Gmail failed
>   [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\getpass.py", line 92
>       return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
>   GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
>   Warning: Password input may be echoed.
>   Press ENTER to continue..

A que se debe?

mi codigo es:

```
import smtplib, socket, sys, getpass

def main():
    print

    try:
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        smtpserver.starttls()
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        print "Connection to Gmail was successful"
        print "Connected to gmail" + "\n"




    except (socket.gaierror,socket.error,socket.herror,smtplib.SMTPException),e:
        print "Connection to Gmail failed"
        print e 
        getpass.getpass("Press ENTER to continue..")
        sys.exit(1)



    print "\n"
    raw_input("pause program")

main()
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que tienes actualmente

Comment: Recien lo agregue

Comment: Erik, lo más probable es que estés ejecutando el Script en un ambiente sin los privilegios adecuados. Para hace un bind a un socket necesitas una acceso como administrador, por lo que debieras probar ejecutar un `cmd` con el "run as administrator" o "Ejecutar como administrador" y en ese shell ejecutar el script, seguramente se abrirá la ventana de la UAC solicitando autorización para permtir el acceso a los sockets.